# tumblr full page scroll effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I've been looking for a library or a solution to implement Tumblr's scroll effect.

I previously worked with libraries like fullpage.js but the thing is Tumbler effect is a bit different.

To be more specified, when you scroll up/down sections cover each other, but in libraries like fullpage.js sections push each other to up and down.

I'll appreciate if you guys have any solution or library to implement this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 2018:

There's an article about it [here](https://alvarotrigo.com/blog/how-create-tumblr-website-effect/). Which makes use of fullPage.js. instead.

---

You are looking for [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling), the small brother of fullPage.js.

You can even use fullPage.js to do exactly the same as long as you use the [parallax extension](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/parallax.html) with the offset value set to 100, and then place all your content in the background element. So it will move at the same time that the background.

The advantage of using fullPage.js is that you'll have plenty of more options, methods and callbacks than when using pagePiling.js, which hasn't been updated in a long time.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for in last 3 days. Cheers mate, thank u